# Failed to Execute C function in PostgreSQL that uses system call to run Python script

Tags: python, c, postgresql, system-calls

I have the following:

```
/* execute_py.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

int
call_py()
{
        printf("Executing your Python script...");
        return system("python36 absolute/path/to/example.py");
}
```

and:

```
# example.py
with open("absolute/path/to/test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("hello world")
```

I compiled the c script into `execute_py.o` and `execute_py.so` then created a function in the PostgreSQL server:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION call_py() RETURNS integer
     AS 'absolute/path/to/execute_py', 'call_py'
     LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

and tried to run the function like this:

```
SELECT call_py();
```

The function returned 0. But when I checked the folder, there is no `test.txt` being generated.

I'm new to C and not sure what had happened. Seeking for help.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was being stupid and forgot to add execution permission to `example.py`.